# How are the predictions obtained?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet

I have been unable to find information on how exactly `predict.cv.glmnet` works.

Specifically, when a prediction is being made are the predictions based on a fit that uses all the available data? Or are predictions based on a fit where some data has been discarded as part of the cross validation procedure when running `cv.glmnet`?

I would strongly assume the former but was unable to find a sentence in the documentation that clearly states that after a cross validation is finished, the model is fitted with all available data for a new prediction.

If I have overlooked a statement along those lines, I would also appreciate a hint on where to find this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for predict.cv.glmnet :

"This function makes predictions from a cross-validated glmnet model, using the stored "**glmnet.fit**" object ... "

In the documentation for cv.glmnet (under value):

"**glmnet.fit** a fitted glmnet object for the full data."